# How to remove blank page in word file using python docx or any other library available in python?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I have a word document in Docx format which has multiple blank pages. I need to delete all the blank pages in the document using python. I have tried to delete empty lines in the document. But it is not working. tried the below code:

```
from docx import *
document=Document("\\doc_path")
z=len(document.paragraphs)
for i in range(0,z):
    if document.paragraphs[i].text=="":
        document.paragraphs[i].clear()
```

The above-mentioned code is not working and deleting all the intermediate empty lines on a page.

Comment: See Word MVP Daiya Mitchell's page *Word Doesn't Know What a Page is* https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html and Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page *Deleting "Blank" Pages* http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BlankPage.htm for context on your problem. Blank pages may or may not be caused by empty paragraphs.